# How can i create a duration chart in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to make a file to track the time I study a certain subject:
[image]

I would like now to make a chart with all the values (that in this case are durations) in the B, C and D columns, but I don't really understand how to do it. When I select the cells and click "create chart" it does the following:
[image]

which is obiously wrong. If i remove "date" from the "series list" in the settings of the chart above i get the following:
[image]
But I don't understand what this represent. How can I do this? Please keep it simple.. This is the first time for me using google sheets

Ps i just realized that that kind of format specifies a time (2am, 3am etc) and not a duration. Is there any format that indicate a duration?

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, I think you should make a 'Gantt' chart. It can be used to display the duration of an activity. It's not exactly an 'easy' task, but there are tutorials you can follow online.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what to do:

1.) Select all of your time columns entirely within the spreadsheet itself (not the graph). Using your posted setup, that would be Col-B, Col-C, Col-D. To do this, just click on the "B" at the top of Col-B, hold down the mouse and drag right to Col-D, then release. If you have more columns than these that will record durations for classes, select those as well.

2.) From the main menu, choose **Format > Number > Custom number format > **. In the field at the top, enter this format: `[h]:mm`

The second chart in your post is actually correct. It's just showing your durations as the decimal percentage of a full day on the Y-axis. The steps above should cause the chart to adjust to showing durations.

Comment: Thank you!! Could I ask you why that works?

Comment: Charts have a section which asks what formatting you want to use for labels. The default is "the same formatting as the corresponding range." If you haven't then set the formatting correctly for the range, you'll get odd labels.